# A global variable of configuration accessible to all the forms classes?

Tags: c#, winforms, configuration

I have a WinForms C# project. It has multiple forms/classes. I have a keyed string in app.config, and would like to use it across all the forms/ classes.

Shall I created a field of string type in each form class, and read the value from app.config, and assign the value to the field?

Or is there a class, so that I can create a field only for that class, read the value once from app.config, and assign it to the field once, and make other forms classes refer to it?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create static class with shared configuration data?

```
public static class ConfigData
{
  public static string ConfigString1 {get;set;}
  public static int ConfigInt1 {get;set;}

}
```

and add "using static yournamespace.ConfigData;" to any class file where you need config data